# Leetcode 739: Daily Temperatures when to use a monotic stack?

Tags: python, algorithm, stack

I was working on https://leetcode.com/problems/daily-temperatures/ and after struggling I realized a monotonically `decreasing` stack helps me solve the problem. I've copied over the question below.

Given an array of integers `temperatures` represents the daily temperatures, return an array answer such that `answer[i]` *is the number of days you have to wait after the* `ith` *day to get a warmer temperature*. If there is no future day for which this is possible, keep `answer[i] == 0` instead. My solution is below.

```py
 def dailyTemperatures(self, temperatures: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        mono_decreasing_stack = []
        N = len(temperatures)
        temps = [0] * N
        for i in reversed(range(0, N)):
            temp = temperatures[i]
            while mono_decreasing_stack and temp >= temperatures[mono_decreasing_stack[-1]]:
                # maintain the monotonically decreasing stack property
                mono_decreasing_stack.pop()
               # do something with the popped element
            if mono_decreasing_stack:
                temps[i] = mono_decreasing_stack[-1] - i
            mono_decreasing_stack.append(i)
        return temps
```

Although in this problem a monotonically decreasing stack is helpful to store and retrieve the "next" warmer day, I realize in other problems a monotonically *increasing* stack is more helpful. Are there some general rules I can apply to decide whether to use a monotonically *decreasing* or *increasing* stack? Am I right in that if the problem instead asked for the *number of days I have to wait after the* `ith` *day to get a colder temperature*, I would use a monotonically *increasing* stack?

Comment: Did your posted code work?   For the question you asked - do you try to run and check your *assumption*?

Comment: yes my posted code solves the problem. I did try to run and check my assumption and what I posted is correct. However I'm looking for general guidance on these types of problems @DanielHao

Comment: No your code will fail with this temperatures *[89,62,70,58,47,47,46,76,100,70]*  Correct output is - *[8,1,5,4, `3`, 2,1,1,0,0]*  BTW, your assumption is prob. correct - try a few cases now.

Comment: yes @DanielHao I forgot to maintain the property of the monotonically decreasing stack, the elements appended to the stack have to be strictly decreasing. Modified my code to be `>=` instead of `>`

Comment: sure! Learning about different approaches always helps me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the value from `mono_decreasing_stack.pop()`, this is the index where you have a lower value than the current value in a monotonic decreasing stack and you need to compute offset as current_index - popped_index

Also not sure why you would want to traverse from the end. You could start from beginning and build a monotonic decreasing stack with the same condition you have i.e.
`temp > temperatures[mono_decreasing_stack[-1]]`

The modified code would be:

```
def dailyTemperatures(self, temperatures: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    mono_decreasing_stack = []
    N = len(temperatures)
    temps = [0] * N
    for i in range(N):
        temp = temperatures[i]
        while mono_decreasing_stack and temp > temperatures[mono_decreasing_stack[-1]]:
            # maintain the monotonically decreasing stack property
            idx = mono_decreasing_stack.pop()
            # do something with the popped element
            temps[idx] = i - idx
        mono_decreasing_stack.append(i)
    return temps
```

And you are right about *number of days I have to wait after the ith day to get a colder temperature, I would use a monotonically increasing stack?*
Just change > sign to < sign in while condition.

Comment: My intuition was to build the temperatures array in reverse order (starting from the end) b/c I noticed the last temperature will always have a value of zero.

Comment: Hmm, the last will end up with zero, because there are no elements ahead of it. :)